# get_context_data y get_queryset

Tags: python, django

-Estoy buscando una forma de poder entender para que sirven estas dos funciones, pero no encuentro los parámetros que reciben estas dos funciones, alguien podría decir los parámetros que reciben **get_context_data** y **get_queryset**

-He estado buscando en Django documentation, pero tampoco encuentro nada claro, ya que luego en muchos videos reciben (**AMBAS FUNCIONES**) parametros distintos y resulta confuso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Básicamente el método `get_queryset` sirve para definir los filtros, este método sustituye al **model** en la vista generíca `ListView` por lo que este método te devolverá el queryset que será utilizado para obtener la data que se mostrará en el Template.

Por otro lado `get_context_data` sirve para pasar información al template diferente al **model** o al queryset, por ejemplo si se quiere enviar aparte de la consulta del `get_queryset` algún otro dato por ejemplo países `Country` en el método te quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```py
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwars):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['countries'] = Country.objects.all()
    return context
```

Y esto te envíara a la vista en el contexto lo siguiente:

> **object_list:** Una variable que devuelve el método `get_queryset`.

> **countries:** Una variable que envías desde el método `get_context_data`.

La ventaja fundamental del `get_context_data` es que puedes enviar tanta información necesites en el contexto. (A esto sele llama extra información).

Answer (score 1):

Ambas funciones reciben un `request` que es el que puedes utilizar para retornar los objetos o los atributos que sean pasados a las plantillas.
Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
def get_queryset(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_autheticated():
        return Model.objects.all()
    else:
        return None
```